# How to remove a button with its slot in Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have created a Qt Widgets Project using Qt Creator wizard(Windows 7, MinGW, 64 bit).
Then I have added a push button `pbClick` to the main window (with mainwindow.ui).
Now right click on the `UI` pushButton and clicked on `Go to Slot`.
This created the following function:

```
void MainWindow::on_pbClick_clicked()
{
    this->close();//added by me.
}
```

in the mainwindow.cpp file.

The program is working fine.

Now I deleted the push button from the user interface  by right clicking *delete*.

And I deleted the above function `MainWindow::on_pbClick_clicked()` manually.

If I try to run the program, an error message comes.

*C:\QtProjects\QtWidgets\build-QtWidgetsTest-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp:67: error: undefined reference to `MainWindow::on_pbClick_clicked()*

The error is coming in the following function

```
void MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        MainWindow *_t = static_cast<MainWindow *>(_o);
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: _t->on_pbClick_clicked(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
    Q_UNUSED(_a);
}
```

defined in the `moc_mainwindow.cpp`

How to completely remove the button along with its click event(slot) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that you've removed the reference to the `on_pbClick_clicked()` function in the header of `MainWindow.h` as well as its implementation `MainWindow.cpp`.

If no other references remain, run `qmake`, which can be found under the "Build" menu.